# Excel 2013 Removed Part: /xl/drawings/vmlDrawing1.vml

Tags: vba, excel

After i do this things in Excel 2013

```
strSaveName = ThisWork.Path & "\" & strExt & ".xlsx"
.SaveAs strSaveName, FileFormat:=51
```

Excel gives the following error when opening this xlsx file:
"Excel found unreadable content in 'newFile.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

Once I click Yes, I receive the following notice:
"Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content. Removed Part: /xl/drawings/vmlDrawing1.vml part.  (Drawing shape)"

Also all coments being deleted.

if i save in another format

```
strSaveName = ThisWork.Path & "\" & strExt & ".xls"
.SaveAs strSaveName, FileFormat:=56
```

everithing goes ok instead warning about not supported formulas in excel 2003

How to fix that and save file as xlsx ?

Comment: Have you tried without `fileformat`?

Comment: Yes, i tryed `.SaveAs strSaveName, 51` and error the same

Comment: lol I meant without that argument at all. Just `.SaveAs strSaveName`

Comment: Yes, everething the same error

Comment: Hmm you must have some data that is ancient or not compatible XD

Comment: So how to determine this data?

Comment: Good question. I don't know :/ At least we know `.vml` is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try run this code on your original file

```
Dim objcomment As Comment

    For Each objcomment In ActiveSheet.Comments
        With objcomment.shape
            .top = objcomment.Parent.top
            .Visible = False
        End With
    Next
```